# React-file-viewer confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, module

I have used FileViewer from 'react-file-viewer' module.

```
import { FileViewer } from 'react-file-viewer';
```

However, I got this error:
`Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-file-viewer'. 'c:/Users/User/Desktop/HCMUT_SSPS/client/node_modules/react-file-viewer/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try 'npm i --save-dev @types/react-file-viewer' if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 'declare module 'react-file-viewe';'ts(7016)`

I have tried to fix like the proposion but it still has error.